# Must the performance measure be fixed before repeated evaluations?

Tags: model-evaluation, methodology

I am preparing an evaluation scheme for a set of binary classifiers. The main purpose is to continuously monitor the performance on a daily basis.

Now, I'm choosing between the two possible designs of the assessment subsystem:

- keeping predictions for a test set and then calculating some set of performance measures over the specified period of time on demand

or

- evaluating the chosen set of metrics on the fly and discarding the predictions

The first one may be somewhat easier to implement in my circumstances, yet I'm worried if it has some flaws from the statistical point of view. How bad is it to variate the performance measures for existing predictions?